# HTML Table with curved linked heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

[image: What I'm trying to achieve in HTML, CSS, JS, Jquery, or a lib]

I'm trying to achieve this type of table so that I can have extended labels for columns. But I don't even know what it's called to try and describe it in a search.

Edit
I can find how to round html borders with CSS. But that doesn't help with linking rows to columns. I can rotate the column header text, but again, that isn't what I'm after.

The closest thing I can come up with is a full table with borders or a background colour to highlight the connection, but this would be squared instead of rounded.

I'm wondering if there is a method of achieving this with css. Or alternatively a library which would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard about something like this. In general, you cannot curve any element like that, supposing that link is normal part of table (tr/td).

I have created some small thing here, making the curvers, than you can add it over your table to make that feeling, but note, that you cannot write inside it, and most umportantly, it will not work, as this will not look precise across browsers and zoom (tested on another projects, where I needed also some circled things)

So you should better design your table in other way.

Anyway, here is a snippet with rounded linked things

```css
.circ, .circ2, .circ3 {
  position:absolute;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.circ{width: 180px;
  height: 180px; top:0; left:0;}
  .circ2{width: 135px;
  height: 135px; top:23px; left:22px}
  .circ3{width: 80px;
  height: 80px;  top:50px; left:50px;}
  
  .container{position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; border:1px dotted black;width:200px; height:200px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="circ"></div>
<div class="circ2"></div>
<div class="circ3"></div>
</div>
```

Als read this - this is full list of transforms, that browsers supports:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: That looks great, but how to align that with the table and the cells?

Comment: that is exactly what I am talking about ... it takes lots of positioning work , you have to make the curves at first place, so hou have to find correct sizes and positioning. And then you take whole div in which the curves are and you place it absolutely over your table... but as I said, theese are borders and they will draw differently across browsers, so you will probably never get good result everywhere. Also if you zoom the page, if can become messy very easily. So my suggestion stays as in post. Design your table in different way.

Comment: Great, that pretty much answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is a close mockup to what you were looking for

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZrXPd

I wrote part of it in SCSS because it's easier for me, and the snippet here is a compiled version of it...

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.round-edges {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.round-edges .round1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 70px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
}
.round-edges .round2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;
}
.round-edges .round3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 33px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}

tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 400px;
}

tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Last Col
    </li>
    <li>
      Middle Col
    </li>
    <li>
      First col
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="round-edges">
    <div class="round1"></div>
    <div class="round2"></div>
    <div class="round3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Something
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some other thing
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Something Completely Different
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Foo
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>
    <td>
      X
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Taking the time to go over the code, and downvote - but not taking the time to write what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score -2):

??? Use id or number + legend

`#1 #2 #3
left mid right
L M R`

Or, may be better, if you create image.

But, you can still use border-radius + position in table row. May be its not work cross-browser, as you wish.
http://border-radius.com
(write 40 to black input box on site, for example)